# Need help identifying this BMX that I was told Is a holy grail of bike from the 80s

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]Okay so I was told that this bike is a holy grail need help figuring out what type of BMX this isn't

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  We will need more pictures of the frame to help. The head tube logo is a great first step, but more information, the better.

Comment: Have you tried asking the person who told you that ?

Comment: One must be careful regarding grail stories. It may be simply grail shaped by coincidence ;)